# Publish API in WSO2 API Manager Publisher to call a WSDL SAP

Tags: web-services, sap-basis, netweaver

We have to publish an API and configuring a SAP WSDL inside.
When we test the connection, we have a time out.

Is there any spécial settings to configure publish an API with a SAP WSDL?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any special settings to publish a SAP-generated WSDL, but have you confirmed that your WSDL is 100% correct?

If your WSO2 installation is external (ie outside your firewall or if you're accessing WSO2 in the cloud), make sure that the URL in your WSDL is the external one and not the internal one. In particular, check the `location` in the `port` definitions for all of your `services`.